# Long paragraphs follow source indents in TeXShop

Tags: indentation, source, texshop

How do I make long paragraphs follow the source indents in TeXShop? This what I usually get:[image]

How do I make succeeding lines follow the indent of the first line? This is so that it would be easier to navigate the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to make TeXShop indent long lines as you want. If you would like this feature to be implemented, you can “vote” for this [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2888386&group_id=155796&atid=797241).

However you might want to consider breaking the long lines into shorter ones and manually indenting as you will. Some of the advantages of doing so are:

- You get to indent however you want. For example, for itemizes I tend to write

  ```
  \item Lorem ipsum ...
        dapibus ac, ...
        ornare nisi, ...
  ```

  which doesn't correspond to any if the common automatic wrapping/indenting
  schemes implemented in text editors.
- The indentation is stored *in* the file, so that yourself and your coauthors can
  “see” it regardless of the editor you use.
- Tools for diffs, file merges and version control benefit from shorter lines
  (which in turn benefit you!).

Comment: Could be wishlist for TeXShop?

Comment: @Kit, I've edited my answer with a link where you can vote for this feature to be implemented.

Comment: @Juan: Hmm, this is the only wrapping/indenting scheme in my editor :-)

Comment: @Hendrik: Is that emacs? I *knew* someone would point out something like this...

Comment: if you are running diffs, short lines are going to be a pain in the ass in the long run. I usually put 1 paragraph one one line, and let my editor wrap it for me.

Comment: @Mica: Yes, letting the editor do the wrap would be more convenient if it also included source indentation.

Comment: @Juan: That was kind of a hidden joke: I said _my editor_, meaning a TeX editor for DOS I started writing 16 or so years ago, and which I still use in a DOSbox. Call me crazy if you wish. That indentation scheme was one of the first things I implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use TeXShop so I can't say for sure, but your problem might lie in the fact that your items are all on one gigantically long line. Consider splitting those up into individual lines that'll fit the width of your screen.

Comment: Actually the individual items are long paragraphs. I was just showing the left edge to illustrate the non-indentation.

Comment: Those paragraphs are all on one line though—the first item is all on line 6, the second is all on line 8.

Answer (score 1):

I know I've already answered this question and you've already accepted an answer, *but* [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has implemented this feature in their latest version.