# TeX-aware source line wrapping

Tags: tools, sourcecode

For [various reasons,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54140/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-hard-wrapping-and-why-is-it-so-common-with) I prefer to have short physical lines in my latex documents, so that the various editors I switch among don't need to soft-wrap the display. But many GUI editors have terrible support for "hard" line-wrapping. The "hard wrap" option in TeXShop, for example, is not comment-aware and is therefore extremely dangerous. Texcenter 2 breaks lines in places that can insert spaces in the output; etc. (Emacs handles all this well, but I can't always use it.)

So the question: What external tools or (non-interactive) command-line scripts can **reliably** hard-wrap latex documents, in a way that does not change the output? For the purposes of this question I am interested in any and all platforms (though OS X-compatible or portable solutions would be most useful to me).

A good tool should also respect newlines in places that are important to human authors; e.g., a good heuristic is not to remove a newline that is immediately followed by a command sequence or comment (perhaps: even if indented).

Obviously, only TeX can handle unusual documents that change the comment character, etc.; but anything else can in principle be handled quite robustly. What tools are there that do so?

Related: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22508/12092) suggests that TextWrangler is one possibility; haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 4):

As usual, I'm quite happy the way emacs+AucTeX handles the situation. Paragraph-formatting via Meta-q is quite nice and helps a lot to improve the readability. The lines are cut below the limit as you set it. It is comment sensitive as you want (adds automatically % in front of the new line, once it got wrapped). If you're looking for a solution beyond emacs, I have nothing reasonable to offer ;)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately emacs proves how well it can be done... and it's a general-purpose editor (and almost-operating system). Why latex-specific editors can't manage such a simple thing is beyond me. :-(

Comment: PS. I'm happy for @Stefan that he's getting upvoted, but since I already stated in the question that emacs handles this properly, this _really_ doesn't answer my question; I'm looking for information on alternatives, please!